# see things I happen to like

Tags: tense, future-time, future-constructions

a. I'm looking at dresses I've never seen before. I might see something I'll happen to like.

b. I'm looking at dresses I've never seen before. I might see something I happen to like.

Is there any real difference in the meanings of these sentences?

Since I have never seen those suits before, (b) could not mean that I happen to like them now.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of the uses of [present simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/present-simple) is for things that are always true. Liking something is often considered to be always true. If you like a dress, you always like it, even if you are not looking at it right now.

It is possible to use like about a single occasion:

> Let's go to a Greek restaurant tonight. I think that you **will** like the food there.

In this case, it is a single future instance, you use **will**, but in your sentences it sounds strange to use **will**: your sentence b is more natural.